# Python not printing anything after request.post

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, waitress

For some reason, and I cannot understand why python won't print anything after a request.post.
The script is python with Flask and is being served using waitress.
the request runs through without issue because the receiving system executes the payload successfully.

below is a snippet from my code with the result
Code

```
print('before Post')
r = requests.post('http://' + TargetServer + ':' + TargetServerPort + '/rest/v2/executions', data=app_json.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
print('after Post')
responseStatus = r.status_code
print(responseStatus)
```

output

```
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://[::]:9100
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:9100
before Post
before Post
before Post
```

The whole code, just removed a route that is working perfectly.

```
import requests
import os
import sys
import logging
import logging.handlers
from flask import abort, jsonify
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from datetime import datetime
from flask import send_from_directory
from markupsafe  import escape
import unicodedata
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read("configuration")


# rotatingHandlerDefect = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename='Defect.log', maxBytes=52428800, backupCount=5)
# rotatingHandlerDefect.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')
# rotatingHandlerDefect.setFormatter(formatter)
# logging.getLogger('').addHandler(rotatingHandlerDefect)

logger = logging.getLogger("webhook." + __name__)

OO_Server = parser.get("config","OOServer")
OO_ServerPort = parser.get("config","OOServerPort")
OO_EndPoint = 'http://' + OO_Server + ':' + OO_ServerPort + '/oo/rest/v2/executions'
print (OO_EndPoint)

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
            SECRET_KEY='dev',
            debug=True
    )
    
    #logging.basicConfig(filename='record.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')

    


    
    
    @app.route('/favicon.ico') 
    def favicon(): 
        return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/favicon.ico')

    @app.errorhandler(Exception)
    #def all_exception_handler(error):
    #    app.logger.warning("Error: " + str(error.code))
    #    app.logger.warning(request.headers)
    #    app.logger.warning(request.json['data'])
    #   print("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
    #    return jsonify(error=str(e))
    
    @app.errorhandler(405)
    def method_not_allowed(e):
        return jsonify(error=str(e)), 405

    @app.route('/DefectSync', methods=['POST'])
    def Defect():
        app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        thread_a = DefectSyncFlow(request.__copy__())
        thread_a.start()
        return 'Connection Successful'
        
    @app.route('/Test', methods=['GET'])
    def Test():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    class DefectSyncFlow(Thread):
        def __init__(self, request):
            Thread.__init__(self)
            self.request = request
            #print(self.request.data)

        def run(self):
            if(self.request.data) :
                #print(self.request.headers)
                oo_json = ""
                headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic *********', 'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                event_server = self.request.json['server_url']
                event_type = self.request.json['event_type']
                sharedspace_id = self.request.json['sharedspace_id']
                workspace_id = self.request.json['workspace_id']
                #print(event_server)
                #print(event_type)
                #print(sharedspace_id)
                #print(workspace_id)
                data = self.request.json['data']
                for dataset in data:
                    entity_phase = dataset['entity']['phase']['id']
                    entity_id = dataset['entity']['id']
                    entity_name = dataset['entity']['name']
                    entity_name = escape(entity_name)
                    #print(entity_name)
                    entity_name = entity_name.replace("'","")
                    entity_name = entity_name.replace('\\','\\\\')
                    entity_name = entity_name.replace('\"','\\"')
                    entity_name = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", entity_name)
                    entity_creation_time = dataset['entity']['creation_time']
                    if dataset['entity']['description'] is not None:
                        entity_description = dataset['entity']['description']
                        entity_description = entity_description.replace("'","")
                        entity_description = entity_description.replace('\\','\\\\')
                        entity_description = entity_description.replace('\"','\\"')
                        entity_description = entity_description.replace("\n","")
                        entity_description = entity_description.replace("\r","")
                        entity_description = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", entity_description)
                        #print(entity_description)
                    else:
                        entity_description = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['owner'] is not None:
                        if 'email' in dataset['entity']['owner']:
                            entity_owner = dataset['entity']['owner']['email']
                        else:
                            entity_owner = 'null'
                    else:
                        entity_owner = 'null'
                    if 'email' in dataset['entity']['detected_by']:
                        entity_detected_by = dataset['entity']['detected_by']['email']
                    else:
                        entity_detected_by = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['severity'] is not None:
                        entity_severity = dataset['entity']['severity']['id']
                    else:
                        entity_severity = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['priority'] is not None:
                        entity_priority = dataset['entity']['priority']['id']
                    else:
                        entity_priority = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['detected_in_release'] is not None:
                        entity_release = dataset['entity']['detected_in_release']['id']
                    else:
                        entity_release = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['sprint'] is not None:
                        entity_sprint = dataset['entity']['sprint']['id']
                    else: entity_sprint = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['defect_type'] is not None:
                        entity_defect_type = dataset['entity']['defect_type']['id']
                    else: entity_defect_type = 'null'
                    if dataset['entity']['application_modules'] is not None:
                        app_data = dataset['entity']['application_modules']['data']
                        entity_application_modules = ""
                        for app_dataset in app_data:
                            #print(app_dataset)
                            entity_application_modules += app_dataset['id'] + ','
                    else: entity_application_modules = 'null'
                    defect_origin_id = dataset['entity']['defectorigin_udf']['id']
                    oo_json = '{"flowUuid": "*********************","runName": "Defect Sync - '+entity_id+'",' \
                    '"logLevel": "STANDARD","inputs": ' \
                    '{"entity_id": "' + str(entity_id) + '",' \
                    '"event_server": "' + str(event_server) + '",' \
                    '"sharedspace_id": "' + str(
                    sharedspace_id) + '",' \
                    '"workspace_id": "' + str(workspace_id) + '",' \
                    '"entity_defect_type": "' + str(entity_defect_type) + '",' \
                    '"entity_name": "' + str(entity_name) + '",' \
                    '"entity_phase": "' + str(
                    entity_phase) + '",' \
                    '"entity_owner": "' + str(entity_owner) + '",' \
                    '"entity_description": "' + str(
                    entity_description) + '",' \
                    '"entity_detected_by": "' + str(entity_detected_by) + '",' \
                    '"entity_severity": "' + str(
                    entity_severity) + '",' \
                    '"entity_priority": "' + str(entity_priority) + '",' \
                    '"entity_release": "' + str(entity_release) + '",' \
                    '"entity_defect_originated": "' + str(defect_origin_id) + '",' \
                    '"entity_creation_time": "' + str(entity_creation_time) + '",' \
                    '"entity_application_modules": "' + str(entity_application_modules) + '",' \
                    '"entity_sprint": "' + str(entity_sprint) + '"}}'
                    print('before Post')
                    r = requests.post(OO_EndPoint, data=oo_json.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
                    print('after Post')
                    responseStatus = r.status_code
                    print(responseStatus)
                    #logger.info((str(oo_json) + '\r\n' + str(self.request.data)))
                    #log.debug(oo_json.encode('utf-8'))
                    


    

    #if __name__ == '__main__':
    #    print("Test12")
    #    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    
    
    return app
```

Comment: The snippet supplied isn't enough to see what's going on - when is this post request executed? In a route? Also, it's not clear from your question what happened after it printed "before Post" - did it stop running or did you stop the process yourself?

Comment: Hi Serge. I will update the code snippet with the whole code, it was running before without issue I just placed the print because it was no longer writing to my logfile. i did stop the process to show it again but here is a newer output with 3 hits. The route calls a thread which will execute the post request.               
'INFO:waitress:Serving on http://[::]:9100'
'INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:9100'
'before Post'
'before Post'
'before Post'

Comment: The issue seems to be around the URL parameter, if I hardcode the URL it works without issue.